# C# LINQ nullable .Where inline null check

Tags: c#, linq

I am attempting to do the following

```
List<JobPhase> jobPhases = new JobPhaseDao().findAll();
jobPhases.Remove(jobPhases.Where(m => m.Name.Contains("Pre")).First());
```

Is there an elegant way to do an inline null check here such that if the list find any matches I can remove nothing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[List.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx) appears to already support this behavior: pass a `null` as the parameter, and it should remove nothing.

To avoid an exception when your `.Where` call returns no matches, use `FirstOrDefault()` instead of `First()`.

Note that if you expect only one item to match the `Where` predicate, you should use `SingleOrDefault` rather than `First`.

That said, it's not entirely clear what you're trying to do: if you have multiple JobPhases that contain "Pre" in the name, you are somewhat-arbitrarily removing one of them from the list. Are you instead trying to remove *all* matching JobPhases? If so, you should explore a different approach, such as using [`RemoveAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a). For example:

```
List<JobPhase> jobPhases = new JobPhaseDao().findAll();
jobPhases.RemoveAll(jobPhases.Where(m => m.Name.Contains("Pre")));
```

Comment: You should use SingleOrDefault only when you *require* the Where call to return no more than one match, and you need to check that it didn't.  If you call SingleOrDefault with linq to objects, you are asking to enumerate the entire collection to confirm that there's no more than one element satisfying the predicate.  Calling FirstOrDefault is more efficient because you'll stop iterating as soon as you find an element to return.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<JobPhase> jobPhases = new JobPhaseDao().findAll()
    .Where(m => !m.Name.Contains("Pre"));
```

Comment: @bhamlin - depends on the return type of `findAll()`.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OP's question - the "null check" seems necessary to guard against calling `First()` on an empty collection...

Comment: @Jakub - Really? Assuming we're not talking about some custom thing, what .Net type implements `Where()` to return a list?

Comment: This won't do the some thing either. OP's example removes only the first jobPhase that has a name beginning with "Pre". This will remove all of them.

Comment: @bhamlin, It doesn't matter what findAll() returns, because Where returns an IEnumerable<T>, which can't be put into a List<T>. You do need a .ToList(). You were right the first time.